# When I run a file which is begin with "#!/usr/bin/perl -w", I get a error: "syntax error at line 153, near "=~ ?""

Tags: perl

When I run a file which is begin with `#!/usr/bin/perl -w`, I get a error:

> syntax error at line 153, near "=~ ?"

I try to add "#!/bin/bash", this error is not append, but I get another

> error:
>   "line 34: syntax error near unexpected token `('"

line 153 in my file:

```
($output_volume =~ ?^([\S]+).mnc?) && ($base_name = $1) ||
  die "sharpen_volume failed: output volume does not appear to be"
  ." a minc volume.\n";
```

line34 in my file:
use MNI::Startup qw(nocputimes);

Comment: Welcome to SO! People are usually only able to help when you post either the full file, or better, a file with just the line that also reproduce the errors.

Comment: That code is Perl. Changing it to /bin/bash would only work if the file were written in bash instead of in Perl. Your Perl file appears to have a bug.

Comment: `use warnings;` is better style than using the `-w` switch, btw. The former only affects the scope it's in, the latter affects all files (Which might include poor-quality modules that weren't written to avoid warnings...).

Comment: Changing `=~ ?` to `=~ m?` (so adding the initial m to the regex) is worth a try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already have two answers that explain the problem.

- `? ... ?` is no longer valid syntax for a match operator. You need `m? ... ?` instead.
- Until Perl 5.22, your syntax generated a warning. Now it's a fatal error (which is what you are seeing). So I assume you're now running this on a more recent version of Perl.

There are, however, a few other points it is probably worth making.

1. You say you tried to investigate this by changing the first line of your file from `#!/usr/bin/perl -w` to `#!/bin/bash`. I'm not sure how you think this was going to help. This line defines the program that is used to run your code. As you  have Perl code, you need to run it with Perl. Trying to run it with bash is very unlikely to be useful.
2. The `m? ... ?` (or, formerly, `? ... ?`) syntax triggers an obscure and specialised behaviour. It seems to me that this behaviour isn't required in your case, so you can probably change it to the more usual `/ ... /`.
3. Your regex contains an unescaped dot character. Given that you seem to be extracting the basename from a filename that has an extension, it seems likely that this should be escaped (using `\.`) so that it matches an actual dot (rather than any character).
4. If you are using this code to extract a file's basename, then using a regex probably isn't the best approach. Perhaps take a look at [File::Basename](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Basename) instead.

Answer (score 8):

```
$output_volume =~ ?^([\S]+).mnc?
```

This *used* to be valid perl and thus might appear in old code and instructional material.

From [perlop](https://perldoc.pl/perlop#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators):

> In the past, the leading m in m?PATTERN? was optional, but omitting it would produce a deprecation warning. As of v5.22.0, omitting it produces a syntax error. If you encounter this construct in older code, you can just add m.

Answer (score 7):

That is Perl code so the first error message is meaningful.

With delimiters other than `//` in the match operator you must have the explicit `m` for it, so

```
$output_volume =~ m?^([\S]+).mnc?
```

It is only with `//` delimiters that the `m` may be omitted; from [Regex Quote-Like Operators (perlop)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators)

> If `"/"` is the delimiter then the initial `m` is optional.

See [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) for a tutorial introduction to regex and [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for reference.

Also note that the particular delimiters of `?` trigger specific regex behavior in a special case.  This is discussed by the end of the documentation section in `perlop` linked above.